# Custom UIButtonPicture in LightningChartJS

Tags: lightningchart

I use `setPictureOff` and `setPictureOn` to set icon for `ButtonBox` element like this:

```
const container = chart.addUIElement(UILayoutBuilders.Row);

container
  .addElement(UIElementBuilders.ButtonBox
    .setPictureOff(UIButtonPictures.Rectangle)
    .setPictureOn(UIButtonPictures.Rectangle)
   )
  .setText("")
```

What I want to do exactly is to have a simple icon button (e.g. clickable button with arrow icon), but I cannot find a way to represent icons that I want. Can I create and add my own pictures that could be used in `setPictureOff/on`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functionality like this at the moment.

The built-in UI system can be used for simple use cases, but otherwise we suggest to use a dedicated front-end library like React, Vue or even direct HTML, and overlay UI content on top of the charts.